# Is there any simple way to solve the determinant of the following two matrices:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is there any other way beside the standard one of calculating the determinant of the two following matrices without it getting long and ugly? This was an exam exercise so I think there must be some other way beside expanding by rows or columns like we usually do.

$\det \begin{pmatrix}1-a&b&a&b\\ \:b&1-a&b&a\\ \:a&b&1-a&b\\ \:b&a&b&1-a\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\det \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\ r&s&t&u\\ r^2&s^2&t^2&u^2\\ stu&rtu&rsu&rst\end{pmatrix}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest adding two rows or columns in both sides, it may make things simpler. For example, in the first matrix, if you sum the first row and the third one, the determinant doesn't change, and there $1-a$ becomes $1$, which is easier. Tricks like that might work, but be careful

Answer (score 1):

For the first matrix, we can write the matrix in the form
$$
M = I + a\underbrace{\pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1}}_P + b \underbrace{\pmatrix{0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0}}_Q.
$$
One elegant approach is to note that the matrices $P$ and $Q$ can be nicely rearranged with a permutation similarity. In particular, if we take $S$ to be the permutation matrix
$$
S = \pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1},
$$
then we find that
$$
SPS^T = \pmatrix{-1&1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&1\\0&0&1&-1},\quad
SQS^T = \pmatrix{0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\\ 1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0}.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\det(M) &= \det(SMS^T) = \det(I + a(SPS^T) + b(SQS^T))
\\ & = 
\det \left[ 
\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1-a & a & b & b\\
a & 1-a & b & b\\
\hline
b & b & 1-a & a\\
b & b & a & 1-a
\end{array}\right] = \det\pmatrix{A & B\\B & A}.
\end{align*}
$$
(If your prefer, this all amounted to switching the middle columns and the middle rows). With the [block-determinant formula given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), we have
$$
\det \pmatrix{A & B\\ B& A} = \det(A - B) \det (A + B)
$$
This finally gives us
$$
\det(M) = [(1 - a - b)^2 - (a-b)^2][(1 - a + b)^2 - (a+b)^2]\\
= [(1 - 2a)(1 - 2b)][(1 - 2a)(1 + 2b)]\\
= (1 - 2a)^2(1 - 2b)(1 + 2b).
$$

---

For the second matrix, one approach is as follows. Let $M$ denote this matrix. Suppose for the time being that $r,s,t,u$ are all non-zero. Note that the dividing the last row by $rstu$ produces the matrix.
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
r & s & t & u\\
r^2 & s^2 & t^2 & u^2\\
1/r & 1/s & 1/t & 1/u}
$$
Cyclically permuting the rows of this matrix produces the matrix
$$
M_2 = \pmatrix{
1/r & 1/s & 1/t & 1/u\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
r & s & t & u\\
r^2 & s^2 & t^2 & u^2
}.
$$
Finally, multiplying the columns of this matrix by $r,s,t,u$ respectively produces the [Vandemonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
$$
M_3 = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
r & s & t & u\\
r^2 & s^2 & t^2 & u^2\\
r^3 & s^3 & t^3 & u^3
}.
$$
You do not say what facts would be at your disposal for this exam, but I suspect that one such result is that the determinant of this final matrix is given by
$$
\det(M_3) = (s - r)(t - r)(u - r)(t - s)(u - s)(u - t).
$$
Some proofs of this result [are presented here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Vandermonde_Determinant/Formulation_1). From there, we can note that the nature of our steps imply that
$$
\det(M_1) = \frac 1{rstu} \det(M)\\
\det(M_2) = -\det(M_1)\\
\det(M_3) = rstu \det(M_2).
$$
Putting all this together, we have $\det(M_3) = -\det(M)$, which means that our final result is
$$
\det(M) = -(s - r)(t - r)(u - r)(t - s)(u - s)(u - t).
$$